# How to install Brackets IDE?

Tags: adobe-brackets

Does anybody know how to install a 64-bit version of brackets 1.4 for Windows?
I have no idea what to do with the .deb file they give you. Please any help is appreciated!

Link: https://github.com/adobe/brackets/releases

Answer (score 1):

If you have a `.deb` file, hopefully your OS is Debian, and you should double-click on it.

Otherwise, you might RTFM … https://github.com/adobe/brackets/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Then you'll probably want to download the Windows version, instead …

Comment: I don't know how to get 64-bit version for windows, only the 32-bit.

Comment: They only list one Windows version. I suppose you could try to build from source if you didn't like it.